# Hide MySQL database from unauthorised/different user

Tags: mysql, cmd

I am working on a SQL query using MySQL.
I had logged in to default user 'root', and created/ added two new user "**user1**" & "**user2**". Under each user I created one database "**database1**" and "**database2**" respectively and gave **ALL PRIVILEGES**. 
Here goes my question now.

How can I hide "**database1**" from "**user2**" and "**database2**" from "**user1**"...?
Is it possible..? Please help thank you..

Comment: Instead of granting all only grant each user the permission they require https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/grant.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `Grant all privileges on *.* to 'user1'@'IP';` & `Grant all privileges on *.* to 'user2'@'IP';` You need to `revoke all privileges on *.* from 'user1'@'IP';` & `revoke all privileges on *.* from 'user1'@'IP';` That way they cannot see all databases.

Then only grant privileges on the databases that each user needs to see/access by executing `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database1.* TO 'user1'@'IP';` & `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database2.* TO 'user2'@'IP';` This is of course assuming you want each respective user to have All privileges on their databases.

Don't forget to `flush privileges` after running the other commands.

Note: not sure what your IP range is or if you are using wildcard (`%`), so I just put `IP`.

When in doubt in the future please refer to [dev.mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/grant.html)